# Learning, exams, math degree

Tags: self-learning, exams, problem-solving

I have only passed the one fourth of my courses so far, which means like one year of the maths undergraduate studies. I live in a different place from where the university i study at is and try to study alone only with books, notes and pdfs from the internet.

Perhaps i have fear of math exams and generally of exams, when i face the topics and problems to prove in the exams i have some ideas but mostly they are wrong.In the past i passed some exams.

When i try to learn what i read i have an approach perhaps wrong. I try to remember all of what i read without missing or forgetting a symbol or word and if i fail to learn this way i think i am not capable of learning and that i do not learn correctly.

I want to get my math degree, passing the exams and finally getting the degree would be okay i think.

What should i do to overcome the fear of math exams and generally exams?Perhaps, should i try to solve math exercises?Is my way of learning wrong? And what is a more suitable way of learning? What should be my schedule or daily program of reading and solving exerises be? If i get stuck at some exercises should i try to find the answers at the books or notes?

Generallly what does a math student use to solve exercises from the theory? Should i learn the proofs-as i try to generally do- of theorems to have a better learning?

Thank you.

Comment: *I try to remember all of what i read without missing or forgetting a symbol or word* --- I couldn't even remember more than about 40% or 50% of the multiplication table (up to $10 \times 10)$ at age 12, and wound up having to invent all sorts of strategies to interpolate between the values I knew. One of the reasons I continued studying math (especially in college, as opposed to science -- physics more specifically -- which I was more interested in during my early teenage years) is that of all the possibilities for a college major, math probably involved the LEAST amount of memorization.

Comment: @Dave L Renfro, Hi Dave. I think i finally found out why i did not go well in math and learning. I need to understand and remember what i read. When i say understand is like someone asks what does it mean?or, what is the meaning?What is meant by this? I can not teach i think another person how to understand something or how to remember something but i could help i think someone try to overcome some learning problems or problem solving problems or problems related to meaning and understanding. In my mind i thought i had the obligation to teach others how to remember or understand.

Comment: @Dave L Renfro, when i say i thought i had the obligation i mean if a person wanted to learn and understand and solve problems and i was the teacher.By trying to first understand and with the help and the reinforcement of understanding try to remember , is a much better way now i think. So, i think each time i read or hear something i should first try to understand and then with this help try to remember. I am not obliged i think to not miss or not forget some words or symbols if the meaning is okay and if the rest is okay and this does not mean my learning is not good , i think it is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Solve more problems.  Take more practice tests.  Experience reduces anxiety and improves performance.

The first time I led a scram drill, on a submerged submarine, I was scared.  After 11 of them, I was pretty salty.